# Добавление кривой в диаграмме

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я сделал диаграмму, не знаю как можно добавить кривую линию.

```
data_names = ['try1', 'try2', 'try3', 'try1', 'try2', 'try3', 'try1', 'try2', 'try3', 'try1', 'try2', 'try3']
data_values = [1, 0.8, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 0.5]

dpi = 80
fig = plt.figure(dpi = dpi, figsize = (512 / dpi, 384 / dpi) )
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})

plt.title('Results')

#ax = plt.axes()
#ax.yaxis.grid(True, zorder = 1)

xs = range(len(data_names))

plt.bar([x + 0.05 for x in xs], [ d * 0.9 for d in data_values],
        width = 0.2, color = 'red', alpha = 0.7, label = '2019',
        zorder = 2)
plt.xticks(xs, data_names)

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation = 25)

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
fig.savefig(r'C:\Users\nikit\Desktop\bars.png')
```

[image: На данный момент]

На данный момент.

[image: Нужно]

Нужно.

Comment: А какого рода кривая вам нужна?

Comment: по верхушкам диаграммы. не могу найти в документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так добавьте после

```
plt.xticks(xs, data_names)
```

отрисовку линии:

```
plt.plot([x + 0.05 for x in xs], [ d * 0.9 for d in data_values])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
t = linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 400)
a = sin(t)
b = cos(t)

plt.plot(t, a, 'r') # plotting t, a separately 
plt.plot(t, b, 'b') # plotting t, b separately 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Если вам не сложно, можете его подстроить под мой код, что бы кривая была по пикам диаграммы. Буду очень сильно благодарен.